# web ui controls and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why will not fill View page of this controller method

```
public ActionResult Person()
    {
        testEntities6 testPersons = new testEntities6();
        IQueryable<person> persons;

        DropDownLst.Items.Clear();
        DropDownLst.Items.Add("proba");

        persons = from i in testPersons.person
                  select i;
        return View(persons);
    }
```

and include namespaces:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
  using MvcKVteam.Models;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
  using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

In view page I put this code:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownLst" runat="server">
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use server controls in MVC. You should be using HTML Helpers instead.

Based on your existing code:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("DropDownLst", Model.AsEnumerable()) %>
```

But I would recommend using a View Model instead of just passing an IQueryable to the View. I also recommend you pick up an MVC book. Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0 is really good, but doesn't cover the 2.0 release.

Rich

Comment: I have error; There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DropDownLst'.
after using your code